# How do you split a string at every n-th character in Swift?

Tags: swift

Like the question says, if I have:

```
XQQ230IJFEKJLDSAIOUOIDSAUIFOPDSFE28
```

How can I split this string at every 8th character to get:

```
XQQ230IJ FEKJLDSA IOUOIDSA UIFOPDSA
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you marked this as a duplicate, when the answer I procured here is better than the jibberish answers in the post you referenced. You're just making Stack Overflow annoying to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement this function

```
extension String {
    func inserting(separator: String, every n: Int) -> String {
        var result: String = ""
        let characters = Array(self.characters)
        stride(from: 0, to: characters.count, by: n).forEach {
            result += String(characters[$0..<min($0+n, characters.count)])
            if $0+n < characters.count {
                result += separator
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

call it this way,

```
let str = "XQQ230IJFEKJLDSAIOUOIDSAUIFOPDSFE28"
let final = str.inserting(separator: " ", every: 8)
print(final)
```

Output will be like this,

```
XQQ230IJ FEKJLDSA IOUOIDSA UIFOPDSF E28
```

This will be generic solution if you want to add any character instead of space, it will work.

Comment: No longer works in Swift 5 unfortunately.

Comment: Here's the Swift 5 version:
```extension String {func inserting(separator: String, every n: Int) -> String {
        var result: String = ""
        let characters = Array(self)
        stride(from: 0, to: characters.count, by: n).forEach {
            result += String(characters[$0..<min($0+n, characters.count)])
            if $0+n < characters.count {
                result += separator
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}```